# Stuck on proof in Coq

Tags: proof-techniques, coq

This is an exercise from Software foundations for my discrete math & functional programming class. I am a little stuck with the end of the code because it works for the first two examples but it doesn't work for my false case and I can't figure out why...

````
(** **** Exercise: 2 stars, standard (eqblist)



  Fill in the definition of [eqblist], which compares

  lists of numbers for equality. Prove that [eqblist l l]

  yields [true] for every list [l]. *)



Fixpoint eqblist (l1 l2 : natlist) : bool :=

 match l1, l2 with

 | nil, nil => true

 | (h1 :: t1), (h2 :: t2) => true

 | _,_ => false

 end.



Example test_eqblist1 :

 (eqblist nil nil = true).

Proof. reflexivity. Qed. (works)



Example test_eqblist2 :

 eqblist [1;2;3] [1;2;3] = true.

Proof. reflexivity. Qed. (works)



Example test_eqblist3 :

 eqblist [1;2;3] [1;2;4] = false.

Proof. reflexivity. Qed. (this one doesn't work! )

```
````

Comment: I'm not sure whether debugging your Coq code is on-topic here.  Any community votes?

Comment: I’m inclined to say it’s more about debugging code than CS principles, but I don’t have much weight

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is wrong. Every pair of lists will evaluate to `true`. You need to actually check that h1 and h2 are the same, and that the lists are the same length.

If I recall the exercises correctly, you may want to look back at `beq_nat` and `andb`.